# FT CRAWL on SQL Server 2012 holds up too many connections

Tags: sql-server-2012, full-text-search

We are facing an issue with Full-Text service on our SQL Server 2012, it seems that it's behind crawling several dbs and once it's running it holds up too many connections, I can confirm that with `sp_Who2`. This eventually brings down the whole SQL Server service and no new connection can be made to it.
We have over 5000 dbs and been operating few years with no issues.
Our only options for now is to disable Full-Text on the db level using `sp_fulltext_database`.
We are basically out of options at this point, is there any way to limit the number of connections FT Crawl can hold on to or at least somehow slow down the process or offload it to off-hours schedule?
We did also tried `sp_configure 'max full-text crawl range', '1'` in hope of a relief but no success!